Light or dark, when picking frozen abalones sealed in clear plastic?
What shade is best? Light or dark? In my village, the store sells solely frozen Australian abalone, sealed in see through plastic.  I am befuddled, as advice on the Internet contradicts!

"Avoid darkened ones."


When selecting fresh abalone, it should be thick, dark, and have no off smells.



Top picture. Bottom.

When selecting fresh abalone, it should be thick, dark, and have no off smells. How do you smell something in a sealed plastic bag? Anyway found this article quite interesting: Abalone, That Delicious Rarity, Being Farmed in Bay Area
